# gcc linker: which input libraries are used?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm debugging some linker issues ("undefined reference" to symbols that are supposed to be in a library that I'm linking with), and I'm not sure whether the compiler is using the right shared library.

The output I'm looking for is like the one produced by `ldd`, that is, a list of libraries with full paths... but I can't use ldd as the compilation fails before producing any output.

The closest I have so far is dumping the library search path and checking the directories one by one for the shared lib in question; I was wondering whether it was a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm debugging some linker issues

You would get *much* better answers if you show the *actual* error and the link command line you used.

Most likely you did something like this:

```
gcc -lfoo main.c
```

where `libfoo.so` is the library that defines the necessary symbol. Read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) to understand why above command line is wrong.

> but I can't use ldd as the compilation fails before producing any output

Your earlier statement said that your *link stage* fails. Compilation and linking are not the same thing, please don't mix them up.

> I was wondering whether it was a better way of doing this

To find out which libraries the linker is using, read `man ld`. On a UNIX system, this command is likely to provide a better way:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-t
```

P.S. Also note that there is no such thing as "gcc linker" -- they are completely distinct tools.

Comment: Thanks for answering not only the question (-Wl,-t does exactly what I was looking for) but also for pointing it out that it was the wrong question after all. The "how does the linker look at command lines" link is really useful, I just used it to fix another linker error...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcc -v` verbose flag to make gcc spit out every thing it is doing while compiling and linking your code.

It will show you the path of the actual libraries where the linker search them and flags it is using to compile your code.

Comment: Indeed, it's useful info, and more than I had before, but it doesn't actually print library paths. Thanks anyway!